# Prompt message after logon

Tags: windows, group-policy, login

I am trying to get the group policy to work where after logon the user gets a message prompt.  I've set the group policy, but the message doesn't show.

I first searched and seen another post with the same issue a year ago, but not sure it was ever resolved or 100% answered.  So I would like to post this question again.

I did a GPresult and see the proper policy is being enforced.

I don't know why it isn't working. Any other suggestions.

Comment: Just to verify, you're setting the following policy, correct?

Computer Configuration - Policies - Windows Settings - Security Settings - Local Policies Security Options :: Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on

Comment: Yes, that is the correct one, well at least the one I am editing.

Comment: @pk That policy will display a message *before* the user logon.  There is not a pre-existing policy for displaying a message *after* logon.

Comment: okay, that should still be okay.  How come I don't see the message then?

Answer (score 5):

Figured this out.  I was doing everything right, HOWEVER you need to specify the Message title for user attempting to log on as well!  As soon as I enabled that, it worked.

Comment: Man, I even thought about suggesting that (since I checked our policy and that's how we had it configured), but I figured that would be a stupid design so I stayed silent.  Now I know.

Answer (score 0):

> Computer Configuration - Policies - Windows Settings - Security Settings - Local Policies Security Options :: Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on

That policy message shows up after you hit Control - Alt - Delete to start logging in.  To show a message after login I would imagine you would need to include that message with your login script.

Comment: really?  That would be cool, and I would be happy with that.  I just can't figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Try rebooting the machine after running "gpupdate /force" in the command prompt

Comment: already tried that a few times.

Comment: The computer in an OU where the policy is enforced?  You can try manually setting the computer to read or enforce the policy in GP management.

Comment: The domain policy might be overwriting your set policy BTW.  Might want to check do not inherit.

Comment: @Xeon, your last comment was an excellent thought.  However, checked it out and all looks okay.  I have a container under the OU for Computers.  So I even added the policy to that, did a gpupdate /force then a gpresult and it see's it.  reboot, still no message.  I checked on the inheritance comment as well.  Amazing how something so little can cause so much frustrations.

Comment: Anybody have anymore thoughts on this.  I haven't been able to get this to work yet?